# The first Button only will be coloured permanently after reopen application

Tags: java, android

I have multiple buttons and I want the button become colour after clicked and reopen again the button is that colour permanently and I want do like when user click on button4, the button4 still colour permanently when reopen the application.

The problem I faced now is I click any button but when reopen again, the first button is colour.I try set the button to array, still same output. In selection page, i select other button, but when reopen again, the first button only got colour.I want know where the problem is for code.

Coding:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar;
Button mRedColor;
Button mGreenColor;
Button mYellowColor;
Button[] b=new Button[2];
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ButtonColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit = getSharedPreferences("ButtonColor", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    final Button[] b = new Button[]{(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRed),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGreen),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYellow),};

    mToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

    if (getColor() != getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i<b.length; i++){

                if(b[i].equals(b[0]) ){

                b[0].setBackgroundColor(getColor());
                b[i].setEnabled(false);

                }
                else if (b[i].equals(b[1])){

                        b[1].setBackgroundColor(getColor());
                        b[i].setEnabled(false);
                }else if (b[i].equals(b[2])){

                    b[2].setBackgroundColor(getColor());
                    b[i].setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

        b[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId())    //so we get its id here
                {
                    case (R.id.btnRed):
                        b[0].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                        storeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                        b[0].setEnabled(false);

                        break;
                    case (R.id.btnGreen):
                        b[1].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                        storeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                        b[1].setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    case (R.id.btnYellow):
                        b[2].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
                        storeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
                        b[2].setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                }


            }
        });

    }

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ButtonColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
    edit=getSharedPreferences("ButtonColor", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

}

@Override
public void onStop () {
    super.onStop();
}
private void storeColor(int color){
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ButtonColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    mEditor.putInt("color", color);
    mEditor.apply();
}

private int getColor(){
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ButtonColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int selectedColor = mSharedPreferences.getInt("color", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    return  selectedColor;
}
}
```

Hope can understand my question, Thanks

Comment: I still need the help, hope other can give me more suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here is the deal:

```java
b[0].setBackgroundColor(getColor())
```

Just replace `0` with `i`:

```java
b[i].setBackgroundColor(getColor())
```

**UPDATE**:
The better way to store index of the last selected button. So instead of color, store button index. That's how you will now which button was selected after app reopen.

Comment: This code make  all button become coloured after reopen again, now i want when i clicked button 2, and after open again application, only button 2 is coloured.

Comment: store index, mean create new method for store last selected button?

Comment: @lunL that's what i mean.

Comment: ok, I try find how to write the index in method, thank for help

Comment: can u show me the code? i am no idea to do, sorry, my java programming skill no so good

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last click index in SharedPreferences；Reopen application check the index and colour the index button.

Comment: but this one i dont know how to do? got link as reference?